# Summary and reverse

Tags: reverse, freemarker, new-operator, counting

I'm just starting with FreeMarker and I didn't get the answer. Maybe somebody can help me?

I want to show: `<#assign test = ["x","y","z"] />` in reverse direction as z,y,x using the list function but I don't know how to do it. If I have: `<#assign ordercount = ["20","40","60"]`, how can I get the summary of all numbers as result using the list function?

Answer (score 0):

**Reverse:**

```
<#assign test = ["x","y","z"] >
${test?reverse?join(", ")}
```

result: z, y, x

**Summary:**

```
<#function sum nums...>
  <#local sum = 0>
  <#list nums as num>
    <#local sum += num>
  </#list>
  <#return sum>
</#function>
${sum(20, 40,60)}
```

result: 120

Answer (score 0):

**Reverse:**

```
[#assign letters = ["x","y","z"]]
[#assign lettersReversed = []]

[#list letters as i]
    [#assign lettersReversed += [letters[letters?size-1-i?index]]]
[/#list]
```

lettersReversed :["z","y","x"]

**Sum:**

```
[#assign numbers = ["20","40","60"]]

[#function sumStringNums input]
    [#local sum = 0]
    [#list input as i]
        [#local sum += i?number]
    [/#list]
    [#return sum]
[/#function]

${sumStringNums(numbers)}
```

output: 120